# Is possible to add background-image for text with CSS3?

Tags: css, background-image

i would like to add **background-image** on text, but i want that only text has background-image and not all div

```
.class {
background-image: url('');
}

<div class="class">
 <p> Site Name </p>
</div>
```

but i don't know if is possible... i tried but nothing
i can add background-image at div not text

Maybe i can to use

```
 background-clip
```

???

I hope that can you help me...

sorry for my english
thanks a lot!

Comment: try this article by Codrops [about background-clip](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/12/experiments-with-background-clip-text/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```
.class p{
    font-size:50pt;
    color: white;
    background: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg') no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Live demo Here https://jsfiddle.net/z2gcy5ym/1/

Comment: it seems like for non-WebKit browsers you'll need to use a fallback. couldn't find other pure css solution at the moment.